# updating from 11.1 to 13.1 or higher

Tags: system-requirements

I am updating computer stored a couple of years.  It is running Ubuntu 11.10 and I want to upgrade to 13.10. With only 3.9 gigs of ram, it appears the store may have been saying that is highest I can use. Is there anything like a tutorial somewhere?  I am new here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both 11.10 and 13.10 are outdated. Use 12.04 LTS (support until 2017), 14.04 LTS (until 2019) or 15.10 (only until July 2016) instead. As you can upgrade directly from 11.10 to 12.04, you should do that in any case. Then you may do another LTS-upgrade  to 14.04. Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release to find out how to upgrade your outdated release.

Comment: And no, 4GB RAM is not a problem. Even 2GB would be enough for most basic stuff. On all versions. If you prefer a more lightweight desktop, consider installing and using XFCE (package `xubuntu-desktop`) instead of Unity.

Comment: If you have 32-bit system,  the limit for making use of RAM is 4 GB, that's true. And there are ways around it. But what I would suggest  ( personally ), create a new installation for 64 bit Ubuntu of an LTS release, 12.04 or 14.04 ; back up your data somewhere - another partition, cloud, external drive or USB; install the new 64 bit install onto the hard drive. There, done.

Answer (score 0):

The system requirements since 11.04 are the same, according to the [Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Ubuntu_Desktop_Edition) are:

- 1000 ΜHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 1024 MiB RAM (system memory)
- 3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB

So there is no need to wait upgrading to 12.04 or even 14.04, but go for an LTS version, that will save you some trouble.